# hide a graph from amChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, landscape-portrait, amcharts

Sorry for my englsih but i'll try to be clever as possible.

I'm working on an web portal for smartphone an I have a problem with amChart. I want to show my graph when the user turn his phone in landscape mode. So I create a bloc for my graph like this:

```
        <div id="graphC2">
            <div id="chartdiv_Cumul" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
        </div>
```

And at the end of my page i wrote some lines of JS...

```
        $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){    
            if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
                document.getElementById("graphC2").style.display = "none";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("graphC2").style.display = "block";  
            }
        });
```

My problem is:

LOCAL: When the user turn his phone in landscape mode for the first time, the graph is always hidden, but it was visible when he turn his phone (landscape) for the seconde time...

ONLINE: Same thing + the graph choose when it was visible...

Thx for your futur responses :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to [revalidate the size](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#invalidateSize) of your chart. Herby keep the chart instance

```
var chart1 = AmChart.makeChart(...);
var chart2 = AmChart.makeChart(...);
```

and call the method after you've changed the visibility of the container

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){    
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        document.getElementById("graphC2").style.display = "none";
        chart1.invalidateSize();
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("graphC2").style.display = "block";  
        chart2.invalidateSize();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong in the first part ... I just put all my chart in a variable (chart1) but the result is the same like before ... :/